# I am interested/ keen on/ enjoy writing blog posts

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, synonyms, sentence-choice

I am trying to express my interest of writing blog posts.

So basically I want to say something like that.

`Furthermore, I enjoy sharing my experience in a form of blog posts, so visit my blog`

It sounds inaccurate to me, especially I am not sure about `in a form of`

The idea is to start with `I like to write blog posts` and end with `so visit my blog`

I want to express this more elegantly. And also if it is possible to replace `enjoy\keen on\like` with a synonym.

Please help to construct a sentence.

I would be grateful for any help.

Thank you.

Comment: A minor correction: it should be "in **the** form of blog posts", because it's a specific form.

Comment: @stangdon thanks for the answer. Appreciate your help. Could you suggest how to construct whole sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "enjoy". In fact, the only changes I would suggest are: ".. in *the* form of..", and I would try to avoid repeating "blog". Maybe "...visit my website".

If you need to avoid "enjoy" you can describe why you have found it enjoyable for example: "I've found recording my experiences in this blog to be both rewarding and educational." This is the "show, don't tell" principle that writers use. Explain why it is enjoyable, rather than just stating it.

Your suggested alternative "I like to write blog posts, so visit my website." is also quite acceptable. But "I am keen to" suggests that it is something that you want to do, but haven't done yet, which isn't your meaning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this sentence will be on my website main page, so the person will be on my website while reading it. 
I try to avoid `enjoy\keen\like' because I previously used them so want to avoid tautology

Comment: Expanded slightly to address this.